# Pages from custom table

Tags: database, templates

I have custom table "catalog" inside wordpress database:

```
id|name|description|slug|price
```

I have template file "catalog" and page "Catalog" where i show all items from catalog table. But how i can show single item from this list as a page?

domain.dev/catalog/ (this part works)
domain.dev/catalog/my-single-item-page (this i can't figure out how to make to work)

how i can use "my-single-item-page " as dynamic variable?

slug = "my-single-item-page";

i have this snippet inside my functions.php file

```php
    function add_query_vars_catalog_item_filter( $vars ) {
        $vars[] = "catalog_item";
        return $vars;
    }
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_catalog_item_filter' );

    function catalog_rewrite() {
        add_rewrite_rule('^catalog/([\w-]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=catalog&catalog_item=$matches[1]', 'top');
    }
    add_action('init', 'catalog_rewrite');
```

but when i go to domain.dev/catalog/some-my-item i got 404 page

I use this custom table because i generate form CSV. And in future it will be simpler for regenerate data

Comment: Have you flushed the rewrite rules? (just visit the permalink settings page)

Comment: @SallyCJ Are you serious? Such a quick thing. How i do not think about that :D. Thank you!!! You can write answer and i will accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code worked absolutely fine for me, so I suspected you forgot to *flush the rewrite rules*.**

Each time after you added code which alters the WordPress rewrite rules, e.g. `add_rewrite_rule()` or code which registers/un-registers a CPT or custom taxonomy with *URL rewriting enabled*, you should always flush the rewrite rules which means WordPress will empty/reset the saved rewrite rules (in the database and `.htaccess` file) and regenerate (and re-save) them which would include your newly *added or updated* rewrite rules.

*How to flush the rewrite rules: Just visit the Settings → Permalink Settings page. And there's no need to click on the "Save Changes" button.*

There's also a programmatic way (see [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/)), but in general, the above trick is the preferred way unless you are writing a plugin where you would for example, call the function during the plugin *activation and deactivation*.